# Stitch together Live streams and Event streams with hls.js

Tags: reactjs, http-live-streaming, hls.js

Im working with an HLS stream that utilizes a Live-to-Vod workflow to manage longer streams and make the Vods readily accessible. However, I am wanting to allow a user to freely go from live to vod and back again seamlessly. Im having trouble coming up with an implementation that allows this. Im not sure what a good direction would be.

I've tried messing around with redundant streams where the VOD and LIVE events overlapped and have tried stitching the manifest files together but because of the encoding changes it has been a bit of a headache and hasn't worked. I'd really appreciate even just a point in the right direction.